# Oracle SQL: How to fill Null value with data from most recent previous date that is not null?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Essentially date field is updated every month along with other fields, however one field is only updated ~6 times throughout the year. For months where that field is not updated, looking to show the most recent previous data

| Date | Emp_no | Sales | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1234 | 100 | Med |
| Feb | 1234 | 200 | --- |
| Mar | 1234 | 170 | --- |
| Apr | 1234 | 150 | Low |
| May | 1234 | 180 | --- |
| Jun | 1234 | 90 | High |
| Jul | 1234 | 100 | --- |

Need it to show:

| Date | Emp_no | Sales | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1234 | 100 | Med |
| Feb | 1234 | 200 | Med |
| Mar | 1234 | 170 | Med |
| Apr | 1234 | 150 | Low |
| May | 1234 | 180 | Low |
| Jun | 1234 | 90 | High |
| Jul | 1234 | 100 | High |

This field is not updated at set intervals, could be 1-4 months of Nulls in a row

Tried something like this to get the second most recent date but unsure how to deal with the fact that i could need between 1-4 months prior

```
 LAG(Group)
    OVER(PARTITION BY emp_no
    ORDER BY date)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the traditional "gaps and islands" problem.

There are various ways to solve it, a simple version will work for you.

First, create a new identifier that splits the rows in to "groups", where only the first row in each group is NOT NULL.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN "group" IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTION BY emp_no ORDER BY "date") AS emp_group_id
```

Then you can use MAX() in another window function, as all "groups" will only have one NOT NULL value.

```
WITH
  gaps
AS
(
  SELECT
    t.*,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN "group" IS NOT NULL
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END
    )
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY emp_no
            ORDER BY "date"
      )
        AS emp_group_id
  FROM
    your_table t
)
SELECT
  "date",
  emp_no,
  sales,
  MAX("group")
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY emp_no, emp_group_id
    )
      AS "group"
FROM
  gaps
```

***Edit***

Ignore all that.

Oracle has IGNORE NULLS.

```
LAST_VALUE("group" IGNORE NULLS)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY emp_no
        ORDER BY "date"
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
             AND CURRENT ROW
  )
    AS "group"
```

Comment: Perfect! ignore nulls is a blessing. Cheers for your help :)